# How to generate requirements, the pros and cons of using a singleton for a db connection?

Tags: java, php, algorithm, class, design-patterns

I have a question regarding design patterns. How can I know that which design pattern will be useful for certain modules?

I am creating a Video Conferencing system in which for database connection I have used the Singleton design pattern for one instance at the same time of database.

Now, I am creating the Chat and Video (one to many) Conference module for that which design pattern I have to follow.

What are the classes and interface I should declare for that.

```
Class Database
Class Chat
Class TextChat Extends Chat
Class VideoChat Extends Chat
```

Is that right way to declare the modules for that?

Comment: What is 'right' for your application depends upon the requirements you are trying to meet and the needs of your users.  Without knowledge of this, how do you expect contributors here to tell you what your architecture should be?

Comment: Actually I want to know that how can I decide the design pattern for my classes and Interfaces?

You can take any example for make decision

Comment: What, exactly, are the classes and interfaces supposed to do?  what are the reauirements upon each class and each interface?  if you just want a list of patterns from which to stuff into your application whether or not they are appropriate, you can find one on wikipedia, or you can pick up a design pattern book

Comment: Should I close this question? is it not give me proper answer here?

Comment: You might try and edit the question so it's answerable.  You might ask about considerations when generating requirements, how to generate requirements, the pros and cons of using a singleton for a db connection, etc.  It just needs specifics and limited scope so it can be answered.

Comment: I don't think you should have one database connection. Connection pooling is much better and often already built-in.

Comment: This is an example of Design Patter I can use in system.
I want to know that In My Video Conferencing System What Design Pattern would be better for performance, security and scale.

Comment: @halfer Why this question is on HOLD. it is different that the particular Design pattern question.

Comment: @AshwinP, partly because it's too broad, and would need a book to answer, and partly because it's subjective, and so would result in discussion rather than a single correct answer. Now, I'm not _personally_ opposed to technical discussions (as opposed to technical questions) but those are the rules as outlined in the Help section. A lot of this knowledge comes with experience, so buy a book on design patterns, and of course do read good-quality OO code (say from an open source project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Design patterns:**
each design pattern solves some problem. You need to describe the problem you have and find a matching design pattern. [sourcemaking.com/design_patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

What Singleton gives you is lazy loading of some instance and the constructor. So, you can load it based on some parameters. If multiple threads access your instance you need to synchronize them. In a static access you don't worry about loading of anything and you just pass what you need to get a DB resource. You can code DB access as number of patterns but DB access ok to be simple static stuff that any threads can access to call the data.

**Database Access:**
The best way to access data is through static rather than instance methods. Singleton is instance, a single instance designed for different solutions than database access.

**Video conferencing software:**
Are you developing Lync or Skype, etc...? Why wouldn't you just use a professionally done software for that, most of which is free?

Comment: Actually I would like to use HTML5 + Google WebRTC so. Thanks for good reply.

Comment: HTML5 is still kind of "in development", so, I don't know how much you can get out of it in your case

Comment: I am only work with Google Chrome so there is no problem.